# JQuery Sortable Scroll, will scroll up but not down

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jsp, jquery-ui-sortable

So my problem is as the title suggests. My work is in JSP but for the sake of clarity I have recreated the problem as best I could in HTML. Essentially, in the main page (non-simplified version), I am using sortable to allow elements to be rearranged in a drag and drop method (moving list items). The page only allows scrolling (bump scrolling) when I am at the bottom of the page which just simply extends the bottom of the containing div and adds the scroll bar. What I need is when there are elements above and below (elements that I have set up to sortable) I need the page/containing element to allow me scroll up and down.

The following code is an incredibly basic recreate, this code allows me to scroll up when I am not at the top of the element but will not under any circumstances allow me to scroll down whilst at any point of the element.

Here is the receation:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({placeholder:"placeHolder", scroll: true, axis: "y", opacity: 0.5});
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
  });
</script>
<style>
  #sortable{
    list-style:none;
  }
  .formatlist{
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .placeHolder{
    border: 2px solid #ff8833;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffee88; 
  }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
  <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="formatSort"><div class="formatlist">NUMERO ONE This is a test on a list that drags LalLalala......</div></li>
    <li class="formatSort"><div class="formatlist">NUMERO TWO This is a test on a list that drags LalLalala......</div></li>
    <li class="formatSort"><div class="formatlist">NUMERO THREE This is a test on a list that drags LalLalala....</div></li>
    <li class="formatSort"><div class="formatlist">NUMERO FOUR This is a test on a list that drags LalLalala.....</div></li>
    <li class="formatSort"><div class="formatlist">NUMERO FIVE This is a test on a list that drags LalLalala.....</div></li>
    <li class="formatSort"><div class="formatlist">NUMERO SIX This is a test on a list that drags LalLalala......</div></li>
    <li class="formatSort"><div class="formatlist">NUMERO SEVEN This is a test on a list that drags LalLalala....</div></li>
    <li class="formatSort"><div class="formatlist">NUMERO EIGHT This is a test on a list that drags LalLalala....</div></li>
    <li class="formatSort"><div class="formatlist">NUMERO NINE This is a test on a list that drags LalLalala.....</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating your issue in [jsFidde](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/pzGgK/). It seems to scroll properly. Can you clarify?

Comment: @apaul34208 - I have played a lot more now, I think this is a firefox issue! to recreate in JFiddle, in firebug change the JFiddle output window to be larger then the visible document size, then the same happens!

Comment: @apaul34208 After more play, chrome and IE both like this (YES... even IE) but firefox says no!

Comment: I'm using Firefox v23 and it is working, strangely not working in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/pzGgK/embedded/result/

Comment: Try whacking the code into an html doc, thats where I am getting problems (except not in IE), I am a little confused to say the least¬!

Comment: IE is a hateful non-compliant browser it seems really odd that it's the only one not giving you problems...

Comment: Irony depresses me /:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've got it, you're missing the document type, I added: `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the very top of the document above the opening `<html>` and it worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> ... and so on
```

jsFiddle adds it automatically, hence the trouble recreating it.

Comment: Got to be kidding me! teaches me to go for a quick re-creation! Now this can help me slowly strip away at the actual product and get to the root of it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Will vote you up just as soon as I am given the opportunity too (>15reputation)!!

Answer (score 0):

the answer by apaul worked for me. Scrolling up worked but scrolling down did not.

In my case I changed
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">`
to
`<!DOCTYPE html>`